# Any reference concerning factorization of partial isometries in $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, invariant-subspace

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. An operator $x\in B(H)$ is called a partial isometry if it is an isometry on Ker$x^{\perp}$.

Two well-behaved classes of partial isometries are *maximal partial isometries* (i.e., isometries and co-isometries) and *power partial isometries*. Indeed we have that:

1. (**Wold-decomposition theorem 1954.**) Every isometry is a direct sum of unitary and unilateral shifts.
2. **(Halmos and Wallen 1970.**) Every power partial isometry is a direct sum of unitary, isometry, co-isometry and truncated shifts.

B. Fishel also obtained a characterization of those partial isometries which are sums of shifts:

3. (**Fishel 1975.**) A necessary and sufficient condition that a partial isometry $x$ (without zero or unitary parts) be the orthogonal direct sum of left and right shifts is that $x^nxH^{\perp}\subseteq x^nH$ or  $x^{*n}xH^{\perp}\subseteq x^{*n}H$.

Q. Does there exist any other factorization(s)  of a partial isometry into some nicer operators?